# DefaultValue and changing values in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, select, onchange

In my react app i have an endpoint that returns user details and another on that returns countries and I'm calling both of them in the `componentDidMount`, i have a country dropdown and it's default value/option should be the country returned from the user details endpoint and it's options should be the countries list returned from the countries endpoint, the problem is when i use the value attribute to set the default value for the select it's always null and it doesn't show a value, so i tried using the `<option selected="selected">{this.state.country}</option>` but the onChange function doesn't work when i use it, so what's the best approach to achieve that, here is the code:

Using the value attribute:

```
<select value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleChange}>{this.renderCountries()}</select>
```

Using the selected option:

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange}>
  <option selected="selected">{this.state.country}</option>
    {this.renderCountries()}
</select>
```

OnChange function:

```
handleChange = event => { 
    this.setState({ selectedOption: event.target.value });
};
```

Rendering options:

```
 renderCountries() {
   return this.state.countries.map(country => (
     <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>
       {country.name}
     </option>
    ));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `this.state.country` to the value returned from the endpoint.

```
<select value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleChange}> . 
    {this.renderCountries()}
</select>
```

The `handleChange` needs to setState for `country` not `selectedOption`. This is because the `value` attribute on select is `this.state.country`

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ country: event.target.value });
  };

  renderCountries = () => {
    return this.state.countries.map(country => (
      <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>
        {country.name}
      </option>
    ));
  };
```

Hopefully this should fix your issue.